# how to get customers who only bought two specific products?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-4

I made a query to get desired result but i am getting multiple customers not according requirements.

```
$builderObj = $this->db->table('customers');
$builderObj->join('orders', 'customers.id = orders.customer_id', 'left');
$builderObj->join('order_products', 'orders.id = order_products.order_id', 'left');
$builderObj->join('order_packages', 'orders.id = order_packages.order_id', 'left');
$builderObj->join('order_package_products', 'order_packages.id = order_package_products.order_package_id', 'left');
$builderObj->select('customers.id, customers.email');
$builderObj->where('customers.deleted_at', null);
$builderObj->where('orders.deleted_at', null);
$builderObj->havingGroupStart()
    ->having('COUNT(DISTINCT(order_products.product_id))', 1)
    ->orHaving('COUNT(DISTINCT(order_products.product_id))', 2)
    ->orHaving('COUNT(DISTINCT(order_package_products.product_id))', 1)
    ->orHaving('COUNT(DISTINCT(order_package_products.product_id))', 2)
->havingGroupEnd();
$builderObj->whereNotIn('orders.order_process_status_id', [OrderProcessStatusModel::PAYMENT_PENDING, OrderProcessStatusModel::ORDER_CANCELLED]);
$builderObj->groupBy('customers.id');
$builderObj->orderBy('customers.id', 'DESC');
$removeRestoreCustomersArr = $builderObj->get()->getResult('array');
return $removeRestoreCustomersArr;
```

Comment: *how to get customers who only bought two specific products?* `.. HAVING SUM( product_id NOT IN ( {product ids list} ) ) = 0`

Comment: I want to get only customers who bought  products (product_id) = 1, 2 ?

Comment: If customers bought products (product_id) = 1, 2 **only** then there is no a row with another product_id. And hence `HAVING SUM( product_id NOT IN ( 1, 2 ) ) = 0` will produce TRUE. If there is a row where the customer bought some another product then NOT IN will produce TRUE, SUM() will produce a value above zero, the whole condition will produce FALSE, and this customer won't be selected.

Comment: HAVING SUM(order_products.product_id NOT IN ( 1, 2 )) = 0
Or SUM(order_package_products.product_id NOT IN ( 1, 2 )) = 0
I added this but not getting required results

Comment: You must solve your task on pure SQL level firstly. See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), especially #5 and #3.